# phpstorm method not found in extends class

Tags: php, phpstorm

Приветствую. В PHPStorm почему-то не подхватывает расширенные классы.
Имею нечто этого
Собственно здесь методы, которые не подсвечиваются

```
class User_Model extends Model
{
    /**
     * @var bool Вошел ли пользователь в систему
     */
    private $is_logged = false;

    /**
     * Access constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
```

Здесь объявлена $model

```
abstract class Controller
{
    /**
     * @var Model Объект модели
     */
    protected $model;
```

Здесь $model определена

[image: User_Controller]

А тут ищется в Model а не User_Model

[image: Profile_Controller]

Что сделать, чтобы он понимал. Ведь $model наследуется и значит в классе B должно подхватится дополнение методов в А. А шторм понимает только родительский Model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы указали `@var Model` вот он от него и отталкивается.

Обновите тип в `User_Controller`.

```
class User_Controller extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var User_Model
     */
    protected $model;

    ...
}
```

Или так:

```
/**
 * Class User_Controller
 *
 * @property User_Model $model
 */
class User_Controller extends Controller
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Я позже проверю @property , а писать всюду $model не хочется, потом где то изменишь ее тип, например, и все сломаешь... Хотя так это работает, посмотрите на скрин

Comment: Только из-за phpDoc ничего не сломается, но дублировать, конечно, не хорошо. Недостаток ``@property`` в том, что при навигации к объявлению - попадёте на него же.

Comment: Получилось, спасибо. По смыслу он и должен переходить сначала на потомка, а потом уже из него в родитель Model. Хотя пока не сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой, пусть будет аккуратно в IDE